# Weierstraß parametrization of minimal surface

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I am currently learning about how to generate minimal surfaces using complex analysis — namely by calculating the Weierstraß parametrization (here's the article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%E2%80%93Enneper_parameterization)).

Now in my lecture notes it is written that given a holomorphic function $f$ and a meromorphic function $g$ (such that at each pole of $g$ of order $k$, $f$ has a zero of order at least $2k$), the resulting Weierstraß parametrization will certainly *locally* be an embedding, but it might not be one *globally*.

Can you please help me out why that is the case? And maybe give an example where we don't get a global embedding?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest answer is this: [Enneper's surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enneper_surface). The Weierstraß representation is as simple as it gets, but the surface clearly crosses itself.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course, thank you very much! (Can't vote you up though, not enough reputation...)